# gulpjs add back in previously ignored paths?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jshint, gulp

When using gulpjs, I want to run jshint on some files (ignoring certain ones), and the concat all the files, including the ones that were previously ignored.

```
// Specify js files but ignore .min.js files
var paths = [ './public/js/*.js', '!./public/js/*.min.js' ];

gulp.task('scripts', function(){
  gulp.src( paths )
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
    .pipe(concat())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/all.min.js'));
});
```

The problem with the above, is that since the `*.min.js` files were ignored from the original source because I didn't want them run through `jshint`, now they are out of the stream and won't be concated.

How do I get around this problem? I have a feeling I need to change my gulp pattern a bit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding back previously ignored paths, try to use `gulp-if` to only perform certain tasks "if" the files match a criteria.

With your example, on top of the head, the following should do (not tested!):

```
var paths = [ './public/js/*.js' ];

gulp.task('scripts', function(){
  gulp.src( paths )
    .pipe(gulpif('!./public/js/*.min.js', jshint()))
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
    .pipe(concat())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/all.min.js'));
});
```

See gulp-if and gulp-match documentations for more on conditions.

Comment: Ah I like that approach. I will try that. Thanks